# remove the content from the beginning to the first blank line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to remove the content from the beginning of the text to the first blank line.

```
--($:~)-- cat example.txt   
pedro
pablo
juan

francisco 
emiliano
martin
```

So, I would delete:

```
pedro
pablo
juan
```

I tried with:

```
sed -n '/^/,/^$/ d' example.txt
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to the network. Please read the formatting guidelines: http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help and format your questions in a better form in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
 sed -n '/^$/{:l; p; n; b l}' file
```

The `-n` suppresses normal output. When you reach the first blank line, which is matched with the pattern `/^$/`, it starts a loop that prints all subsequent lines.

Comment: Thats work perfect !! i added

sed -i -n '/^$/{:l; p; n; b l}' example.txt;sed -i '1d' example.txt

cat example.txt
francisco 
emiliano
martin

Comment: I see that you are new to Unix SE. If you are satisfied with an answer, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^$/,$p' file
```

or:

```
sed -e '/^$/,$!d' file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^$/{p++};p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With a recent `ksh` (you need `ksh93s` or above), you could do:

```
cat <example.txt <#""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 1,/^$/c\\ -e '' <infile >outfile
```

...would also work.

As opposed to `1,/^$/d` the `c\`*`<EOF>`* command doesn't `d`elete the address range, exactly, but rather `c`hanges the whole block to a single string. And so this will not remove the first blank line from output - because it `c`hanges the whole first occurring text block in input *(as delimited by the first occurring blank line)* to a single blank line.

Comment: Your posts shouldn't be cropping up in the "low quality posts" queue! Can you expand this a little to explain to Teb why yours would work but theirs doesn't, or something?

Comment: @roaima - who is *they*?

Comment: _They_ is a gender neutral he/she pronoun referencing Teb, the person who asked the original question. Perhaps our versions of English don't coincide so I'm sorry it wasn't clear.

Comment: @roaima - no, I don't think so. Looking at your comment now it is unmistakably clear to whom it was you referred. Somehow my initial reading of managed to miss entirely the two words *to Teb*. Weird.